# android studio - bluetooth discovering ACCES_COARSE_LOCATION not granted

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-bluetooth

I am training coding on android studio, I am coding an activity that use bluetooth. I am able to enable/disable the bluetooth. but I am in trouble while I am trying to discover devices. The bluetooth doesn't find any device it seems that the ACTION_fOUND never trigger..
The code has no error, and the application runs well.
I found out that the permission ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION is not granted. It may cause the error ?

Does anyone can tell how to grant the permission ?

I followed the following tutorial :
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth

Here is my code..

```
package com.example.kartouche;

import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class BluetoothActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    /** Declaration des variables privés
     * - p_bluetoothAdapter : représente le bluetooth de l'appareil
     * - p_acces_btn_bluetooth : représente le bouton logique d'activation et désactivation du bluetooth de l'appareil
     * -
     * -- */

    private     BluetoothAdapter p_bluetoothAdapter;
    private     Button p_access_btn_bluetooth;
    private     Button p_btn_discover_device;
    private     ListView p_list_device;



    int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION = 1;
    private static final int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 0;
    private static final int REQUEST_DISCOVER_BT = 1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_bluetooth);

        p_access_btn_bluetooth  = (Button)   findViewById(R.id.btn_access_bluetooth);
        p_btn_discover_device       = (Button)   findViewById(R.id.btn_discover_device);
        p_list_device           = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv_list_devices);



        /** ETAPE 1
         * Implementation Bluetooth qui objective le bluetooth de l'appareil. -- */

        p_bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        if (p_bluetoothAdapter == null)
            {Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Bluetooth non disponible sur cette appareil",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}


        if (getApplicationContext().checkSelfPermission("android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION") == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        {
            Log.e("[MESSAGE]","ACCES_COARSE_LOCATION GRANTED");
        }
        else
        {
            Log.e("[MESSAGE]","ACCES_COARSE_LOCATION NOT GRANTED");
        }


        /** Textualisation du bouton p_acces_btn_bluetooth*/

        if(!p_bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled())
            {p_access_btn_bluetooth.setText("ACTIVER BLUETOOTH");}
        else
            {p_access_btn_bluetooth.setText("DESACTIVER BLUETOOTH");}

        /** ETAPE 2
         * Vérification de l'etat d'activation de l'appareil, Si le bluetooth n'est pas activé alors nous l'activons (resp) et changeons le texte du bouton -- */

        p_access_btn_bluetooth.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                Button btn_logique_text = (Button) p_access_btn_bluetooth;
                String buttonText = btn_logique_text.getText().toString();

                if (!p_bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled())
                {
                    Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
                    startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
                    p_access_btn_bluetooth.setText("DESACTIVER BLUETOOTH");
                }
                else
                {
                    p_bluetoothAdapter.disable();
                    p_access_btn_bluetooth.setText("ACTIVER BLUETOOTH");
                }
            }
        });
        /**
         * ETAPE 3
         * Analyse des appareils à proximité. -- */
        p_btn_discover_device.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(!p_bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled())
                    {Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Le bluetooth doit être activé pour effectuer l'analyse", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}
                else
                    {
                        p_bluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"début d'analyse ...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
            }
        });

        // Register for broadcasts when a device is discovered.
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
        filter.addAction(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED);
        filter.addAction(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED);
        registerReceiver(receiver, filter);

    }//OnCreate



    // Create a BroadcastReceiver for ACTION_FOUND.
    private final BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();

            List<String> p_device_bluetooth = new ArrayList<String>();
            ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(BluetoothActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,p_device_bluetooth );
            p_list_device.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);


            if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action))
            {
                Log.e("[MESSAGE]","Device enfin trouvé..");
                BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                String deviceName = device.getName();
                String deviceHardwareAddress = device.getAddress(); // MAC address
                p_device_bluetooth.add(deviceName);
                arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

        }
    };// BroadcastReceiver

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        unregisterReceiver(receiver);
    }//onDestroy

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed(){
        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class));
        finish();
    }//OnBackPressed

}
```

Here is the xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".BluetoothActivity">


    <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/btn_access_bluetooth"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_access_bluetooth"
        android:layout_width="345dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:text=""
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_discover_device"
        android:layout_width="345dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:text="Analyse bluetooth a proximite"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.492"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.584" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

here is the manifest xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.kartouche">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
```

Comment: Yea you need to request that permission from the user. I think you need fine and coarse actually. Could be wrong.

Comment: What do you mean from the user ? is it from the IDE ?

Comment: Look into requesting permissions for android. There is a lot of info around it.

Comment: yes indeed you were right, it was about requesting permissions ... thanks you :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you checked for the permission, however, did not ask the user to grant the permission. I would recommend following this [developer documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting) on this.

Hence, instead of just printing the logs, you might have to prompt the dialog to the user to grant your app the permissions that you need.

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
        CONTEXT, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) ==
        PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        Log.e("[MESSAGE]","ACCES_COARSE_LOCATION GRANTED");
else {
    // You can directly ask for the permission.
    // The registered ActivityResultCallback gets the result of this request.
    requestPermissionLauncher.launch(
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION);
    Log.e("[MESSAGE]","ACCES_COARSE_LOCATION NOT GRANTED");
}
```

And you have to override the `onRequestPermissionsResult` in your activity/fragment where you are asking for that.

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE:
            // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
            if (grantResults.length > 0 &&
                    grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // Permission is granted. Continue the action or workflow
                // in your app.
            }  else {
                // Explain to the user that the feature is unavailable because
                // the features requires a permission that the user has denied.
                // At the same time, respect the user's decision. Don't link to
                // system settings in an effort to convince the user to change
                // their decision.
            }
            return;
        }
    }
}
```